# Creating Custom JSON Mapper in Swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift4, codable, decodable

Here performing two tasks :

**1. Convert Dictionary to Model Object

 2. Convert Model object to Dictionary**

Wrote down following codes and its working perfectly :

```
JsonMapper.Swift

class JsonMapper
{
    /**
     *@Method     : decodeUser
     *@Param      : Dictionary of type [String:Any]
     *@ReturnType : User  ( which is model )
     *@Description: Responsible for mapping Dictionary to Model object
     */
    func decodeUser(userDict:[String:Any]) -> User?
    {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        var objUser: User?
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: userDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
            objUser = try decoder.decode(User.self, from: jsonData)
            print("✅ User Object: \n",objUser)
        } catch {
            print("❌ Error",error)
        }

        return objUser ?? User(id: "", type: “”,salary:””)
    }

    /**
     *@Method     : encodeUser
     *@Param      : User
     *@ReturnType : Dictionary of type [String:Any]
     *@Description: Responsible for mapping Model object User to Dictionary
     */
    func encodeUser(modelObj:User) -> [String:Any]
    {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        var objProfileDict = [String:Any]()
        do {
            let data = try encoder.encode(modelObj)
            objUserDict = (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any])!
            print("✅ json dictionary: \n",objProfileDict)
        }
        catch {
           print("❌ Error \(error)")
        }

        return objUserDict
    }

}
```

**User Model :**

```
struct User:Codable
{
    let id           : String
    let type         : String
    let salary       : String

}
```

Above code works perfectly fine, no problem.

Now the issue is :
1. Everytime i need to convert Dictionary into any model , here you can see Model User is fixed so i want to convert above code in generic model so that , i will pass any model and then it return me the result.

When i pass Dictionary it should return me the model which i will specify during run time , i want to make this generic for every model , so that Dictionary could be convert into any of specified model.

Kindly provide your valuable inputs.

**Note : 
1.Dont want to use any 3rd party lib like ObjectMapper , etc.

Comment: @vadian , could you help me in this , or you can suggest me any link so that i can enhance above code . Thanks

Comment: I would use embedded Swift Codable protocol, I don't see any advantages in your implementation.

Comment: Your comments and question suggest you want to convert objects to and from JSON, but the above code converts objects to and from [String: Any], which is not JSON. What's the goal? If it's to create and consume JSON, then as Martin says, just use Codable. That's what it does (and you're already using it). It's not clear what the JSONSerialization step is for.

Comment: @RobNapier thanks for your suggestion , but i want to create a common method which map any dictionary value to model object , i dont want to specify the model name as i did ( by using User ) , so for this i want to create a common method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name `JsonMapper` is misleading here. What you really mean is a dictionary mapper. Your approach is fine. If you want it to be generic, just pass the type. I'd probably do it this way:

```
extension JSONDecoder  {
    /**
     *@Method     : decodeUser
     *@Param      : Dictionary of type [String:Any]
     *@ReturnType : User  ( which is model )
     *@Description: Responsible for mapping Dictionary to Model object
     */
    func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from dictionary: [String: Any]) throws -> T
    {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary)
        return try decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
    }
}
```

And similarly for `JSONEncoder`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rob Napier for your valuable inputs.